# Do I need a database to handle my website content?

Tags: html, mysql, json, database, filtering

So I'm building a website that contains information about a bunch of different animal species. I will have a list of 500 items, that should be able to be filtered and sorted by different criteria. For example, I will have a 'country selection' option. If Brazil is selected, the Capuchin monkey among other animals (living in Brazil) should be added to the list.

I could see myself making a list with 50 species with no problem, as the HTML would be manageable. But would having 500 items in a list with filterabilty even be possible without using some sort of database?

I was thinking of just pairing animal items from the list with certain filter criteria. For example, Capuchin monkey with "Brazil", "Mammal", "Omnivore", etc.
And when e.g. "Mammal" is selected in the filter, all animals paired with that property (all mammals of the list) is added to the list, or if not paired with the property, then removed from the list.

As you probably can tell, I'm really uneducated on how to go about creating this filterable list. Down the road I might even look into adding a search function.

After pluggin in all content, I would never need to change anything. I've read that databases should only be used if you have dynamic content.

I wouldn't list all 500 items on the same page, as that would make it **very** slow. I would have 10 items per page.

I don't need a solution per se. I just wish to be pushed in the right direction. 
Should I look into MySQL? Can a filterable list of 500 items be possible with just HTML/CSS/Javascript? I am somewhat familiar with javascript, and have read that JSON might be able to provide the things I need.

Sorry if my question is vague or if I'm in the wrong anywhere (this is my first post). Please ask for any clarification and **any** advice or suggestion is **greatly** appreciated.

Thanks,
Manne

Comment: It can be managed without a server, and then JSON is the way to go. Design a JSON that has all the data organised as you want it, and then write the JavaScript to load it and render the page.

Comment: Thanks! What if there are many pages? Can an item on page 3 really be removed without a database?

Comment: removed from what? From the page? Yes. From the JSON? Yes, but not permanently. If your data is not static, and users must be able to delete things from it, then you need a server to maintain and store what is the latest version.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yes, I meant the page. Now I'm on track! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need a database. Have a look at this very robust jQuery plugin that will easily allow you to sort/filter/search 500 items in JavaScript alone:
https://datatables.net/

There are examples that are powered from JSON alone so I would suggest you simply store your data in a JSON file until you grow large enough that you need to change that (if you ever do).

Here is an example where the data is pulled from a .txt file:
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the answer I was looking for. I had a hunch JSON could work without knowing much about it. And I am so glad not to have to learn MySQL or some hard database system. Will definetely check out that plugin. This site is amazing! :)